Visualise only Correlation Plot in R-Markdown
The below code is used to visualise a correlation matrix using the corrplot package.
The goal is to only show the plot. However, on the R-Markdown file where the output is a docx. The code below shows both the plot and correlation values. (See img attached).
How do I run this code such that only the plot is produced in the document?
ti.corr.plot <- corrplot(cor(ti.pilot.numeric, use="complete.obs"), order = "hclust", tl.col='black', tl.cex=.75, method = "circle")
ti.corr.plot 



Could you please share your rmarkdown (mainly what is your yaml header)? So we can reproduce your code.

Don't include the second line ti.corr.plot , as this returns the text but doesn't draw the plot ... the first line draw the plot

Note that the echo = FALSE parameter may be added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot and the results = 'hide' parameter to prevent the correlation results to show.
In your example this means:
---
title: "Untitled"
output: word_document
date: "2024-05-14"
---

```{r code, echo=FALSE, results='hide'}
ti.corr.plot <- corrplot(cor(ti.pilot.numeric, use="complete.obs"), order = "hclust", tl.col='black', tl.cex=.75, method = "circle")
ti.corr.plot 
```

Reproducible example:
---
title: "Untitled"
output: word_document
date: "2024-05-14"
---

```{r code, echo=FALSE, results='hide'}
a <- plot(pressure)
a
```


To me, this answer may not be wrong because it geniunly answers to "How do I run this code such that only the plot is produced in the document?".
